# How to set how apps invoke firefox (stop using -remote openURL)

Tags: firefox, configuration

I have a Xubuntu 14.04 user whose "Thunderbird can't open links anymore - they just take [her] to the home page" (default home page). Started happening recently.

Digging into the issue I found that Firefox 36 stopped supporting `-remote "openURL()"`, which is what clicking on links both in Thunderbird and LibreOffice was invoking: running `ps aux | grep firefox` reveals it is invoked as

`/usr/bin/firefox -remote openURL(http://www.example.com)`

On my own machines (Lubuntu and Ubuntu Unity, both 14.04), Firefox is being invoked from clicked links simply with

`/usr/bin/firefox http://www.example.com`

Where is this configured? I'm going to assume it's an environment setting (as it affects the shell call).... but where is it...?

Web search results are a bit too full of cruft, I appreciate I may be just lacking the right terminology....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not so much a Linux + Firefox issue, but specifically an Xfce configuration which is the culprit.

(EDIT - it was a combo firefox + old apps issue. firefox have since patched the issue with 36.0.1 release)

Answer obtained [on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2267439&p=13237847#post13237847)

This being the fix

```
sed -r -e 's/^(X-XFCE-Commands(WithParameter)?=)%B -remote "openURL\(.+?\)";(.+)$/\1\3/' -i /usr/share/xfce4/helpers/xfce4-firefox.desktop
```

And [this being the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1425972)